# laptop motherboard processor upgrade

Tags: laptop, memory, cpu, motherboard, upgrade

i have a Toshiba satellite pro LAPTOP with 80 GB hod 512 MB ram and 1.8 GHz celeron processor and manufactured in 2007. i was wondering is it possible to upgrade the processor along with the motherboard?? the software's i want to run on my laptop wont run if i only upgrade the ram, i need to upgrade the processor and motherboard too.
I have already asked some technicians but they say that, it is not possible to upgrade processor in a laptop.

Comment: No; laptops are designed very specifically to fit certain motherboards and they are not easily procured nor sold to consumers.  Additionally hardware has changed significantly since 2007

Comment: Why doubt the techs? That is like going to the doctor, getting a second opinion, then going to strangers for a diagnosis and cure.

Comment: SO I CAN JUST INCREASE THE RAM FOR SPEED. THAT'S IT ,RIGHT???

Answer (score 0):

In your situation you can't upgrade your system since the laptops are designed in such a way that they can fit or can only contain specific motherbaords and the celeron processors are very old one.